# Call COleDispatchDriver::CreateDispatch with specific dll version

Tags: com, ole

I have some projects in MFC6 and one project which is written in DotNet 4. The communication between the MFC projects and the .Net project is via COM and the COM Server is on .Net side. The COM server is registered via RagAsm.exe. In MFC I create an Instance of this COM Server like this:

```
CreateDispatch( _T("PROGID.namespace") )
```

The problem is, that the COM Server is used by different projects. So if I want to increase the version number of my com server dll due to code changes, I had to register it again with RegAsm. Now there are two versions of this dll in my registry. But when I call the CreateDispatch method, the program everytime tries to load the newest one. That means, that the projects, which include the older versions, won't be able to find the correct dll. It seems it is not possible to specify a version when calling CreateDispatch().

Is there another posibility to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`ProgID` would resolve into `CLSID` and then eventually to COM server binary. If you would like to have two different COM servers present in the system, why don't you use "version-dependent" (as opposed to version independent you used in your code fragment above) `ProgID`'s with different versions.

- [ProgID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688254%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) vs [VersionIndependentProgID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542717%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [COM registration of PROGIDs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2006/01/10/511279.aspx)